# Is it possible to connect a Raspberry Pi 0 to the USB port of a router, to connect to the internet?

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, usb-power, gadget

Recently I read ([in articles such as this one](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/)) that it is possible to use the Raspberry Pi Zero in 'USB/Ethernet gadget mode'.

Now my modem has two USB ports, which the manual says can be used for file sharing or printer sharing.

It might be wishful thinking, but I was wondering if it might be possible to connect through this USB port with the router's internet, allowing the raspberry pi zero to:

1. Connect to the internet
2. Receive power
3. Broadcast its presence (using e.g. mDNS) to all locally connected computers, so it can receive requests from them.

Comment: "which the manual says can be used for file sharing or printer sharing" - no mention of ethernet, so, no

Comment: The Raspberry Pi can do that. The question is if the router can do it, but that is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. So asking here is not the right place.

Comment: What's the model of your modem/router?

Comment: It is a ZyXel VMG8324-B10A